# PHP do action every x days

Tags: php, cron

Does anyone know how to schedule a php file to take an action every x weeks?

I would prefer to use PHP.

Comment: You'd have to set it up to check if X time has passed since the last check. This would usually be done on a page load (for example when loading the home page of a website). However - this method is extremely unreliable, as it requires the page to be visited for the event to fire, and it could affect page load times. CRON jobs are the way to go with this I'm afraid.

Comment: `i don't really use cron jobs.` then you should start now, as it's the only sane way to do this.

Comment: what's the problem with cron jobs? cron is just a scheduler. it can execute PHP, or any other script/program you want. cron is not a "language".

Comment: Don't be a fool. Use a cron job if they are available to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use cron jobs.  You can schedule a PHP script to run via cron, so really all you need to do is write that script and read the cron documentation for 10 minutes or whatever such that you can configure the script to run.  Cron is extremely simple to configure, do not fear it.

Answer (score -1):

php scripts are executed "only" by browser, (for sure) you will need a cron that will execute bash script with somthing like this :

```
php myscript.php
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  PHP does not require a browser to run.  You can directly run PHP scripts in cron assuming you have PHP CLI installed. No need for bash script at all. In fact, that is all your bash script is doing there (invoking PHP CLI).

Comment: That's why i've put "only" between double quotes, but yes you are right, the bash step is not neccesary, i have in mind "executing more than one command" that's why, but thanks for pointing this out.